# Debugger does not show an error when running the application

Tags: java, android, debugging

I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio Giraffe and used the debugger when debugging the application, but it does not show what the problem is, as it did before.
Now I only receive this message:
(Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:56713', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:56713', transport: 'socket')
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmg8a.png)

although before, for example, he described the error more precisely:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61a5M.png)
I'm not very well versed in Android Studio and could have made a mistake myself somewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.